# Not getting response from Lane Control Board

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to get inputs/outputs from a LCB(lane control board),which in serial. I'm using prolific usb-serial as the interface . I'm new to programming,but i've managed to get send/receive inputs when i shorted pin 2 and 3 of DB9 together .  But when i plugged the db9 connector to the LCB , it can send , but not receiving any .

I'm using VS2010 in Windows 10.

Below are my snippets ;

```
namespace serialPort_wengweng
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    byte[] DataReceived = new byte[4096];
    byte[] DataTransmitted = new byte[15] { 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    //------------------------------------LCB input properties here-START------------------------//
    String LCBInput;
    Boolean i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8 = false;
    //------------------------------------LCB input properties here-START------------------------//


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.serialPort1.DataReceived +=new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);

    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Connect button pressed .. ");
        //if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
        //{

        //}
        //else
        //    MessageBox.Show("");
        if (btnConnect.Text == "Connect")
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = Convert.ToString(cboPortNames.SelectedItem);
            serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cboBaudRate.SelectedItem);
            serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(cboDataBits.SelectedItem);
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), cboHandshake.SelectedItem.ToString());
            serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cboStopBits.SelectedItem.ToString());
            serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cboParity.SelectedItem.ToString());
            try
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
                serialPort1.Open();
                progressBar.Value = 100;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
        }
        else
        {
            btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            txtTX.Text = String.Empty;
            txtRXAll.Text = String.Empty;
            txtRXParsing1.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");

    }

    void UpdateTextBox(TextBox objTextBox, String DataParsing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Update Text Box...");
        objTextBox.AppendText(DataParsing);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    void ReceivedData(TextBox objTextBox, String DataParsing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In ReceivedData...");
        if (objTextBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<TextBox, String>(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { objTextBox, DataParsing });
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    private void PrintValues(ArrayList ar, ComboBox objComboBox)
    {
        Console.Write("Printing Values... ");
        try
        {
            if (objComboBox.Name == "cboPortNames")
            {
                foreach (var v in ar)
                {
                    objComboBox.Items.Add("COM" + v);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var v in ar)
                {
                    objComboBox.Items.Add(v);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException nie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nie);
            Console.WriteLine("Print Values T.T");

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("In Form Load()");
        GetPortNames();
        GetBaudRate();
        GetDataBits();
        GetParity();
        GetStopBits();
        GetHandshake();
        txtTX.Text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DataTransmitted);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    void GetPortNames()
    {
        Console.Write("Getting Port Names..");
        ar.Clear();
        foreach (String s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            ar.Add(s.Substring(3));
        }
        ar.Sort();
        PrintValues(ar, cboPortNames);
        cboPortNames.SelectedIndex = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    void GetBaudRate()
    {
        Console.Write("Getting BaudRate..");
        ar.Clear();
        ar.Add(110);
        ar.Add(300);
        ar.Add(1200);
        ar.Add(2400);
        ar.Add(4800);
        ar.Add(9600);
        ar.Add(19200);
        ar.Add(38400);
        ar.Add(57600);
        ar.Add(115200);
        ar.Add(230400);
        ar.Add(460800);
        ar.Add(921600);
        PrintValues(ar, cboBaudRate);
        cboBaudRate.SelectedIndex = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    void GetDataBits()
    {
        Console.Write("Getting Data Bits..");
        ar.Clear();
        for (int i = 5; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            ar.Add(i);
        }
        PrintValues(ar, cboDataBits);
        cboDataBits.SelectedIndex = 3;
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }



    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("In Data Received ..");
        int i = 0;
        string dtString="";           
        string[] dtArray; // data string saving in here

        Thread.Sleep(500); // wait data ready
        while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0) // if data ready in buffer
        {
            DataReceived[i] = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte()); // read data serial & saving to array byte
            i++;          // counter buffer
        }

         if (i == 15 && DataReceived[14]==15)
         {
            dtString = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DataReceived); // convert array byte to string
            dtArray = dtString.Split((char)44); // parsing string data with separator char(44)
            ReceivedData(txtRXAll, dtString); // complete receive data show in here
            ReceivedData(txtRXParsing1, dtArray[0]); // data first show in here
             }
         Console.WriteLine("Done!");
     }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Button Exit Pressed..");
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Force quit serial port", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            Application.Exit();

        }
        else {
            Application.Exit();
            Console.WriteLine("Serial port closed,quitting app now.");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Button Send Pressed..");
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shoulda write something.");
            var collector = new DataCollector("COM6", ProcessMeasurement);
            serialPort1.Write(txtTX.Text);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            //Console.WriteLine(serialPort1.Read());
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Not receiving anything", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    private void ProcessMeasurement(List<byte> bytes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In process measurement...");
    }

    private void GetHandshake()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get Handshake ...");
        try
        {
            ar.Clear();
            foreach (String s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Handshake)))
            {
                ar.Add(s);
            }
            PrintValues(ar, cboHandshake);
            cboHandshake.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException nie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nie);

        }
    }

    private void GetStopBits()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get StopBits ....");
        try
        {
            ar.Clear();
            foreach (String s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StopBits)))
            {
                if (s != "None") ar.Add(s);
            }
            PrintValues(ar, cboStopBits);
            cboStopBits.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException nie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nie);

        }
    }

    private void GetParity()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get Parity ....");
        try
        {
            ar.Clear();
            foreach (String s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Parity)))
            {
                ar.Add(s);
            }
            PrintValues(ar, cboParity);
            cboParity.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException nie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nie);

        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is DataCollector class,

```
namespace serialPort_wengweng
{
class DataCollector
{

    private readonly Action<List<byte>> _processMeasurement;
    private readonly string _port;
    private SerialPort _serialPort;
    private const int SizeOfMeasurement = 4;
    List<byte> Data = new List<byte>();

    public DataCollector(string port, Action<List<byte>> processMeasurement)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in Data Collector ..");
        _processMeasurement = processMeasurement;
        _serialPort = new SerialPort(port);
        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortDataReceived;
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            var count = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
            var bytes = new byte[count];
            Console.WriteLine(_serialPort.Read(bytes, 0, count));
            AddBytes(bytes);

        }
    }

    private void AddBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        Data.AddRange(bytes);
        while (Data.Count > SizeOfMeasurement)
        {
            var measurementData = Data.GetRange(0, SizeOfMeasurement);
            Data.RemoveRange(0, SizeOfMeasurement);
            if (_processMeasurement != null) _processMeasurement(measurementData);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: You can't open device twice.  One in send method and other in receive method if you have pins 2 and 3 shorted together on same port.  They must share the same port and open only once.  So you code for testing must have an option to share the same instance of the serial port.

Comment: hi,mind to explain a little extra in terms of code-wise?@jdweng

Comment: You have in receiver :  _serialPort = new SerialPort(port);  Then in form : serialPort1